# Filter php array and keep only oldest data on duplicate data

Tags: php, arrays, filter, associative-array

I've an array in PHP that can have **multiple same labels**, but **creation date** for each one is different. I try to **filter** my array and **keep only old created data when duplicates labels exists** in my array.

The array look like this :

```php
$data = [
     [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => "Same label"
            [created] => "15/01/2022" //recent data
        )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => "Same label"
            [created] => "11/01/2022" //oldest data to unset
        )
     [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => "Label alone"
            [created] => "18/01/2022"
        )
]
```

And have to be like this :

```php
$data = [
     [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => "Same label"
            [created] => "11/01/2022"
        )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => "Label alone"
            [created] => "18/01/2022"
        )
]
```

Actually, I've tried with an `array_search()` but **process is long** if they are a lot of data. **I can remove duplicate data** but I don't know **how to filter by created date only on duplicate labels** in my array...

```
$data = [];
foreach ($prs as $pr) {
  $exist = array_search($pr->getLabel, array_column($data, 'label'), TRUE);

  if (!$exist){
    $data[] = [
          'label' => $pr->getLabel(),
          'created' => $pr->getCreationDate(),
    ];
  }
}
```

I saw that there are also `array_filter()` function, `array_key_exists()` and other good functions.

Can you help me please ?

I'll add more info as I progress, but I can't show all page or processes (just example because they are confidential data).

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way might be doing a dual sort by label and by date. Then after sorting, you can loop the collection and compare the current and the next label.

If the next label is different from the current or the last one in the collection, then add the item to the `$result` array.

The example uses a [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `<=>` for the comparison in the usort function and is available since php 7

```
$data = [
    ["label" => "test1","created" => "31/12/2022"],
    ["label" => "Same label", "created" => "13/01/2022"],
    ["label" => "Same label", "created" => "15/01/2022"],
    ["label" => "Same label", "created" => "11/01/2022"],
    ["label" => "Label alone","created" => "18/01/2022"],
    ["label" => "test1","created" => "30/12/2022"],
];

usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a["label"] === $b["label"]) {
        return DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $a["created"]) <=> DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $b["created"]);
    }
    return $a["label"] <=> $b["label"];
});

$result = [];
$last = count($data) - 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    if ((isset($data[$i + 1]) && $data[$i + 1]["label"] !== $data[$i]["label"]) || $i === $last) {
        $result[] = $data[$i];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Label alone
            [created] => 18/01/2022
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Same label
            [created] => 15/01/2022
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => test1
            [created] => 31/12/2022
        )

)
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/XlEof).